# Constantly refactoring my own code... a very bad practice

Tags: refactoring

I have a strange question here.

Am I the only programmer here that constantly feels like I must rewrite / refactoring my own codes ?

Sometimes I do it only because I *think* the speed might be improved, or simply because I believe
the code could be easily imported in a later project.

Hey, sometimes only because it looks *cleaner* for my eyes.

Am I sick ? Am I too perfectionism ? Am I the only one having that problem ?

Comment: It's a great habit to have when you are learning or trying stuff. But in production, such as for published products, that's not a good one: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html

Answer (score 17):

Take a look at [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development).  The basic premise is:

1. write a failing test
2. write code to make the test pass
3. aggressively refactor

As a general principle I think aggressive refactoring is a good idea - why have any more code than you really need.  The difficulty comes in two parts, first, why refactor without a purpose and second, how do you know you haven't functionally changed the refactored code if you don't have a suite of tests against which you can test the refactored version?  TDD is an answer to both of those things.

I would encourage you to get in the habit of refactoring, but I would also encourage a practice like TDD so you don't break your code as you do it.

HTH

Comment: This is something to keep in mind : "To not break your code as you refactor".

Answer (score 9):

You are probably just experiencing iterative understanding of the problem. You make a stab for it and then when you are done, you have gained some new insight. This new insight you apply, only to learn that you have a new insight again, so you toss out part of the code and rewrite that.

You should not change code to be faster if you *think* it is. You should *measure* through profiling or wall-clock runs. And you should know to what level you need the code improved. Some code need very little speed improvement to be adequate.

Answer (score 7):

No, you're not alone. I'd say this is exactly what makes a good programmer - being never satisfied with what you're doing, aspire to improve yourself instead of repeating same things over and over again.

Comment: This what I call "bad habbit" usually slows down my own projects. Ofc I do not have deadlines on them.

Comment: "Time doesn't matter. Only life."

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes I refactor to make it easier to read or run faster, or easier to extend. However in the real world with deadlines and working for yourself, you can only afford to do it if you have a reason to do it!

Comment: Fortunatly, this usually not happen on a code someone else did years ago and I have to fix. I'd be more happy to rewrite it completly but it's impossible. So I adopt the same "old" and "nasty" way to code then the original owner. I do not pretend my way is better. But I have met codes with no indentation and sometimes the guy didn't know how to revert if statement. Eg: `if (i > 3 && i < 5) { } else { //code }`. On my own project with no deadlines though, I could spend hours refactoring my own codes.

Answer (score 3):

I have found this rule-of-thumb useful:
"I should not spend more time refactoring than in implementing user-requested functionality."

I might have lots of other ideas on how the code could be improved, but I find it useful to improve it a little, each time I work on it, rather than trying to achieve "perfection" all at once with all code.

It's like the boy scout motto:  Leave it better than when you found it.

Answer (score 3):

In the early stages of a project you should refactor constantly. You are probably not going to hit on the best solution straight off and requirment changes can make a previously perfect solution suboptimal.

However once you have been through a couple of integration and UAT test cycles I would start to be cautious about refactoring. After all you have invested time and effort to verify the code you have; refactoring will waste this test effort and require the whole test cycle to be repeated.

Answer (score 2):

personally i'd much rather work on code like the above/by someone than code by someone who just leaves it after the first attempt. just be sure not to get into [gold plating](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/12/gold-plating.html).

Answer (score 2):

It all depends, if you can afford refactoring, meaning, you don't have other more important tasks in your queue then refactoring into "easier to read" code is always a good thing ;)

It also depends in the situation.  If you are part of a bigger team then refactoring could mean faster learning of your code by other developers.

While refactoring sometimes you uncover issues/cases not seeing by QA or text fixture, but it is also possible give birth to other issues that may go unseen... something to keep in mind.

I'd say continue refactoring a piece of code if you:

- don't have more important tasks in your queue
- you are fixing a performance related issue
- other team mates think your code sucks (messy code) and needs to be organized better! in this case you are the only developer, so you need to judge your own stuff
- you wrote 40 lines of code for something YOU KNOW could be written in 2 lines, but needed to get it out fast

Messy code = declaring variables all over the place, not using object oriented principle, not encapsulating code snippets and re-writing the same code multiple times, looping everywhere! nasty joins, no comments, etc... etc...

Anybody has more cases?

Answer (score 2):

You're asking about both rewriting *and* refactoring, and I'm afraid the answers are different.  If you are constantly refactoring, you should essentially never need to rewrite.  Refactoring, done well, puts your code into ideal state for its current needs, *without* rewriting.  That's a fine thing.

You list a number of reasons for it:

1. because the speed might be improved;
2. because the code could be easily imported in a later project;
3. because it looks cleaner.

Of these, I would say discard #1  and #2, and stick with only #3.  Here's why.  Refactoring should not change behavior, so refactored code ought to perform identically to the original (there are some edge-case caveats to this, but never consider refactoring as an optimization approach).  The optimization rules are:

1. Don't;
2. See Rule #1;
3. When you absolutely must, **profile**, then optimize only the slow bits.

And optimization is typically more a matter of rewriting than refactoring.  Refactoring can put you into a better position to optimize (Extract Method comes to mind), but it typically won't make your code more performant by itself.  So don't refactor "to make your code faster;" refactor in the course of making your code faster, because you are optimizing - not on a whim.

With respect to reusability - [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it).  When the "later project" comes along - if ever - and you know there's something you could borrow from a prior project, if only it were a little different - that's the time to redesign, to meet the new needs.  Before that project exists, you have already refactored the code of the first project to ideally meet its (single-project) needs; only when the new need comes along is another design more desirable.  Don't anticipate.  Wait for the need to drive your design.

Bottom line: refactor to make the code better for its immediate needs.  Make it readable, make it maintainable.  Use refactoring in support of other operations, as well - but not in anticipation of them.  And don't feel bad about refactoring all the time.  If something looks wrong in your code, it's good to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I do the same. In the long run, I hope it will make me write code cleaner, faster, more reusable, etc. right away. And I do believe, that it is already happening. I think more and more about a new line of code, before I hack it in. So I hope to do less refactoring in the future. But believe that I will only get there, through the refactoring.